# Play Framework Mailer process cannot connect to GMail account

Tags: playframework, smtp, gmail

I need to send email from a Play application using the Play Mailer (https://github.com/playframework/play-mailer).

In my GMail account, I have two-factor authentication turned on, which is company policy -- I cannot turn off.  So my password being used is an Application Specific password I generated through my GMail account (https://support.google.com/mail/answer/185833?hl=en).

I also cannot turn on "less secure apps" (https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/6010255?hl=en).

I have changed my email and password values to generic ones for this post.

For Play Mailer, I have these parameters in my application.conf:

```
# Mailer
# ~~~~~
play.mailer {
  host="smtp.gmail.com"
  port=587
  ssl=true
  tls=true
  user="myemail@email.com"
  password="mypassword" # This is the application specific generated password
  debug=false
  mock=false
  from="thisemail@email.com"
}
```

I am sending an email using this code:

```
/**
 * Send mail with the new password.
 *
 * @param user
 *            user created
 * @throws EmailException
 *             Exception when sending mail
 */
private void sendPasswordChanged(User user) throws EmailException {
    String subject = Messages.get("mail.reset.confirm.subject");
    String message = Messages.get("mail.reset.confirm.message");
    Mail.Envelop envelop = new Mail.Envelop(subject, message, user.getEmail());
    Mail mailer = new Mail(mailerClient);
    mailer.sendMail(envelop);
}
```

which calls this code from the Mail.java class:

```
public void sendMail(Mail.Envelop envelop) {
    EnvelopJob envelopJob = new EnvelopJob(envelop, mailerClient);
    final FiniteDuration delay = Duration.create(DELAY, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    Akka.system().scheduler().scheduleOnce(delay, envelopJob, Akka.system().dispatcher());
}

static class EnvelopJob implements Runnable {
    MailerClient mailerClient;
    Mail.Envelop envelop;

    @Inject
    public EnvelopJob(Mail.Envelop envelop, MailerClient mailerClient) {
        this.envelop = envelop;
        this.mailerClient = mailerClient;
    }

    public void run() {
        Email email = new Email();

        final Configuration root = Configuration.root();
        final String mailFrom = root.getString("play.mailer.from");
        final String mailSign = root.getString("mail.sign");

        email.setFrom(mailFrom);
        email.setSubject(envelop.subject);
        email.setBodyText(envelop.message + "\n\n " + mailSign);
        email.setBodyHtml(envelop.message + "<br><br>--<br>" + mailSign);
        for (String toEmail : envelop.toEmails) {
            email.addTo(toEmail);
            Logger.debug("Mail.sendMail: Mail will be sent to " + toEmail);
        }

        mailerClient.send(email);
        Logger.debug("Mail sent - SMTP:" + root.getString("play.mailer.host")
                + ":" + root.getString("play.mailer.port")
                + " SSL:" + root.getString("play.mailer.ssl")
                + " user:" + root.getString("play.mailer.user")
                + " password:" + root.getString("play.mailer.password"));
    }
}
```

When setting `mock=true` in the application.conf, I can see the email being created correctly with all the correct values:

```
[info] play.api.Play - Application started (Dev)
[info] application - mock implementation, send email
[info] application - subject: Account Access Attempted
[info] application - from: thisemail@email.com
[info] application - bodyText: You (or someone else) entered this email address
when trying to change the password.  However, this email address is not on our l
ist of registered users, and so the attempted password reset has failed.

 null
[info] application - bodyHtml: You (or someone else) entered this email address
when trying to change the password.  However, this email address is not on our l
ist of registered users, and so the attempted password reset has failed.<br><br>
--<br>null
[info] application - to: myemail@email.com
```

However, when I set `mock=false`, I receive this error:

```
[error] a.d.TaskInvocation - Sending the email to the following server failed :
smtp.gmail.com:587
org.apache.commons.mail.EmailException: Sending the email to the following serve
r failed : smtp.gmail.com:587
        at org.apache.commons.mail.Email.sendMimeMessage(Email.java:1410) ~[comm
ons-email-1.3.3.jar:1.3.3]
        at org.apache.commons.mail.Email.send(Email.java:1437) ~[commons-email-1
.3.3.jar:1.3.3]
        at play.api.libs.mailer.CommonsMailer$$anon$2.send(MailerPlugin.scala:10
2) ~[play-mailer_2.10-3.0.1.jar:3.0.1]
        at play.api.libs.mailer.SMTPMailer.send(MailerPlugin.scala:127) ~[play-m
ailer_2.10-3.0.1.jar:3.0.1]
        at play.api.libs.mailer.CommonsMailer.send(MailerPlugin.scala:109) ~[pla
y-mailer_2.10-3.0.1.jar:3.0.1]
        at play.api.libs.mailer.MailerClient$class.send(MailerPlugin.scala:44) ~
[play-mailer_2.10-3.0.1.jar:3.0.1]
        at play.api.libs.mailer.CommonsMailer.send(MailerPlugin.scala:83) ~[play
-mailer_2.10-3.0.1.jar:3.0.1]
        at models.utils.Mail$EnvelopJob.run(Mail.java:104) ~[classes/:na]
        at akka.dispatch.TaskInvocation.run(AbstractDispatcher.scala:40) ~[akka-
actor_2.10-2.3.13.jar:na]
        at akka.dispatch.ForkJoinExecutorConfigurator$AkkaForkJoinTask.exec(Abst
ractDispatcher.scala:397) [akka-actor_2.10-2.3.13.jar:na]
Caused by: javax.mail.MessagingException: Could not connect to SMTP host: smtp.g
mail.com, port: 587
        at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.openServer(SMTPTransport.java:1972) ~
[mail-1.4.5.jar:1.4.5]
        at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.protocolConnect(SMTPTransport.java:64
2) ~[mail-1.4.5.jar:1.4.5]
        at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:317) ~[mail-1.4.5.jar:1.4.5]
        at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:176) ~[mail-1.4.5.jar:1.4.5]
        at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:125) ~[mail-1.4.5.jar:1.4.5]
        at javax.mail.Transport.send0(Transport.java:194) ~[mail-1.4.5.jar:1.4.5
]
        at javax.mail.Transport.send(Transport.java:124) ~[mail-1.4.5.jar:1.4.5]

        at org.apache.commons.mail.Email.sendMimeMessage(Email.java:1400) ~[comm
ons-email-1.3.3.jar:1.3.3]
        at org.apache.commons.mail.Email.send(Email.java:1437) ~[commons-email-1
.3.3.jar:1.3.3]
        at play.api.libs.mailer.CommonsMailer$$anon$2.send(MailerPlugin.scala:10
2) ~[play-mailer_2.10-3.0.1.jar:3.0.1]
Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Unrecognized SSL message, plaintext conne
ction?
        at sun.security.ssl.InputRecord.handleUnknownRecord(InputRecord.java:710
) ~[na:1.8.0_101]
        at sun.security.ssl.InputRecord.read(InputRecord.java:527) ~[na:1.8.0_10
1]
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:973) ~[n
a:1.8.0_101]
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.
java:1375) ~[na:1.8.0_101]
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1403
) ~[na:1.8.0_101]
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1387
) ~[na:1.8.0_101]
        at com.sun.mail.util.SocketFetcher.configureSSLSocket(SocketFetcher.java
:548) ~[mail-1.4.5.jar:1.4.5]
        at com.sun.mail.util.SocketFetcher.createSocket(SocketFetcher.java:352)
~[mail-1.4.5.jar:1.4.5]
        at com.sun.mail.util.SocketFetcher.getSocket(SocketFetcher.java:207) ~[m
ail-1.4.5.jar:1.4.5]
        at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.openServer(SMTPTransport.java:1938) ~
[mail-1.4.5.jar:1.4.5]
```

I have tried different combinations of:

```
port=587
ssl=false
tls=true
```

and

```
port=465
ssl=true
tls=false
```

But they all give me the same error.

I cannot enable IMAP or POP3 on my Gmail account here at work - policy does not allow this.

Are there better examples or samples than what I am using in the Mail.java class?

Answer (score 1):

Looks like it was as simple as setting `ssl=false`...

My updated play.mailer config...

```
# Mailer
# ~~~~~
play.mailer {
  host="smtp.gmail.com"
  port=587
  ssl=false
  tls=true
  user="myemail@email.com"
  password="mypassword" # This is the application specific generated password
  debug=false
  mock=false
  from="thisemail@email.com"
}
```